# Make navbar with 4 columns

Tags: html, css, web, navbar

i want to have 4 columns in my navbar like shown in the picture:

[image]

And the text inside the boxes should be centered, like in the middle of the box. Its importent that thy're boxes so that i can apply "border-bottom" to it. Can somebody pls help, i cant figure it out myself. Heres what i got so far:

```css
header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 0px 10%;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
}

.logo {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #707070;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.nav__links a,
.cta,
.overlay__content a {
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #707070;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav__links {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
}

.nav__links li a {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 225px;
    height: 70px;
    float: left;
}

#active {
    border-bottom: 8px green solid;
}

.cta {
    padding: 9px 25px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 136, 169, 1);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease 0s;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <a class="logo" href="/">filmfestwilsdruff.de</a>
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav__links">
                <li><a href="#" id="active">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">blabla</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">blabla</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">blablabla</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <a class="cta" href="#">Contact</a>
    </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Please do not use Google drive for images when SO itself can host the image. Reason? You might delete the image from your drive, making your question, and the possible answers, less understandable to people other than you.

Comment: OK, I changed the image in the question for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) To Align Content**

[Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) is great to align content vertically and horizontally.

- Add `display: flex` to the parent element of the items to be centered
- [justify-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) will align content on the x-axis (horizontal)
- [align-items](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) will align content on the cross-axis (vertical)

Append the following CSS styles to `.nav__links li a`

```css
.nav__links li a {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

**2) To Align #active Bottom Border**

Using a [box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) to replicate the bottom border with a value of `inset` so it's inside the content element.

```css
#active {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -8px 0 green;
}
```

```css
header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 0px 10%;
    background-color: #efefef;
}

.logo {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #707070;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.nav__links a,
.cta,
.overlay__content a {
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #707070;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav__links {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
}

.nav__links li a {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 225px;
    height: 70px;
    float: left;
}

#active {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -8px 0 green;
}

.cta {
    padding: 9px 25px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 136, 169, 1);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease 0s;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <a class="logo" href="/">filmfestwilsdruff.de</a>
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav__links">
                <li id="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">blabla</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">blabla</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">blablabla</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <a class="cta" href="#">Contact</a>
    </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can center horizontally et verticaly using 2 lines of CSS :

```
    text-align: center; /* center the link */
    line-height: 70px; /* match the height to align in the middle */
```

Here's the snippet:

```css
header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 0px 10%;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
}

.logo {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #707070;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.nav__links a,
.cta,
.overlay__content a {
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #707070;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav__links {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
}

.nav__links li a {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 225px;
    height: 70px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center; /* center the link */
    line-height: 70px; /* match the height to align in the middle */
}

#active {
    border-bottom: 8px green solid;
}

.cta {
    padding: 9px 25px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 136, 169, 1);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease 0s;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <a class="logo" href="/">filmfestwilsdruff.de</a>
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav__links">
                <li><a href="#" id="active">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">blabla</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">blabla</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">blablabla</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <a class="cta" href="#">Contact</a>
    </header>
</body>
```